# How to crop Listview data upto scrolling position in android?

Tags: android, listview, crop

I have a listview with lot of items...for that listview i need to crop the data upto the scrolling position..below is the image for clear explonation..

![image: Listview cropping]

In the above image contains listview with lot of items and when the cropping coordinates are dragging then the listview will scroll and when we stops the dragging then the listview image will crop for htat position..I really dont know how to implement this concept ...

I googled a lot but didn't find the solution..and even i dont know how to implement crop feature as a custom and is it possible to crop a listview data or shall i convert to image??

Can anybody advise me..because i strucked at this position in my application..

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can convert Any Layout in Bitmap. And then you can manage crop feature. In this way you can part your 'this feature' in two easy parts.

Comment: Thanks for comment.. First.,How to convert a listview to bitmap?@SharpDeveloper

Comment: public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) 
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else 
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}

Comment: This will work but listview's visible  items only will be in bitmap. I think your need is also this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this methos and create listview bitmap and then use default crop functionality of camera. May be helpful to solve your problem.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 600,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null) 
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else 
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: This code was not not return the entire listview bitmap...just ersturns the visible items

Comment: Yes it will return only visible items. You can crop only that much which is visible. If u will use listview, you will never get items which are not visible. Listview only handles items which are visible.

Comment: I am not sure but you should use Scroll view instead of ListView. You will get items which are beyond visible area.

Comment: Ok.,its fine i got an idea that i wrote all the views on webview..through this i capture the entire webview and i get one bitmap...and i set that bitmap to imageview which shows all the views as in the webview...through this how can i crop upto scrolling position of imageview?

Comment: IN otherwords just see the PhotoCrop app from googleplay exactly what i want....please suggest me how do i implement custom cropping like in photo crop app?

Comment: I haven't try for custom crop UI design. You can use transparent view and manage touch x y points. to manage UI for Selection. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38480/discussion-between-santosh-and-sharpdeveloper)